# Im new to laravel. i have Multiple Checkboxes. Its validation is not working

Tags: laravel, validation

Im working on laravel. Validation is not working for multiple checkboxes

[i have Multiple Checkboxes and its validation not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCD8e.png) [This is My controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9vs4.png) All errors are showing but (ticket_restrictions) does not show

Comment: Do not post your code as images. **Code is text** and can be copied, pasted and manipulated, **images cannot**. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75605346/edit) and include your code as properly formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
$request->validate([
    'ticket_restrictions' => 'required|array',
    'ticket_restrictions.*' => 'string|min:8|and other validation',
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-array